# Crossblooded Bloodrager, Form of the Dragon + Abyssal bulk

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bloodline

If I were to have a crossblooded bloodrager select [abyssal bulk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo-bloodrager-bloodlines/abyssal/) and the [Form of the dragon bonus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo-bloodrager-bloodlines/draconic/) at level 16. Would these stack or would only FOTD apply?

Comment: Are you asking if you'd be a Large (Form of the Dragon 2) or Huge Dragon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Bigger or a dragon but not a bigger dragon

On the subschool [polymorph](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) says

> You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time. If a new polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect, such as wild shape), you can decide whether or not to allow it to affect you, taking the place of the old spell. In addition, **other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell.** (Emphasis mine.)

As the [draconic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo-bloodrager-bloodlines/draconic/) bloodrager bloodline's supernatural ability **dragon form** is based on the [*form of the dragon II*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/form-of-the-dragon-i) spell—a spell of the polymorph sybschool—, the [abyssal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo-bloodrager-bloodlines/abyssal/) bloodrager bloodline's supernatural ability **demonic bulk**—which is like an exceptional *enlarge person* spell—won't ever effectively stack so as to effectively increase the bloodrager's size category when the bloodrager has used the dragon form ability.

Ask the GM if the demonic bulk ability is suppressed while the bloodrager is using the dragon form ability *or* if the demonic bulk ability fails outright when activated while the bloodrager is using the dragon form ability.

Comment: Your last sentence seems to have a pretty straightforward answer-- the player decides which one affects them.  But you're right otherwise, +1.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet actually, RAW, only Form of the Dragon would be effective. Enlarge Person/the effect of Abyssal Bulk is not a Polymorph effect so it only falls under the line HICC bolded